# I am getting a warning when I iterate through the character pointer and check when the pointer reaches the null terminator

Tags: c

```
 char message[10];

 //I then loop through the message and I get an error in the below if statement.

 if (message == 'send') {
  ...//do something
 }
```

The error I am getting is:

```
 multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]
         if(message == 'send'){
                   ^~~~~~  
letusex4.c:17:16: warning: comparison between pointer and integer
         if(message == 'send'){
```

Comment: You cannot use `==` to compare strings, and even if you could you would want `"send"` instead of `'send'`

Comment: The answer is in the error. You are trying to compare a string to an array pointed to by 'message'. C does not do string comparisons by itself as the first answer shows how to do it with a library.

Answer (score 0):

Double quotes and single quotes have very different meanings.  Also, you cannot use `==` to compare two strings.  You should use double quotes and `strcmp`:

```
if( strcmp(message, "send") == 0 ){ ...//do something }
```

and make sure that `message` is a properly null-terminated string.